# Why can't I remove autodesk from startup?

Tags: windows-10, autodesk-inventor

When I look at my startup programs, I see autodesk turned on:

[image]

I turn it to off, but when I close and repoen this window, I see it on again.

How can I turn it off for good?

Comment: Try to remove it form Task Manager. Or from this registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

Comment: •Open the Task Manager, click the Services tab, and then right-click AdAppMgrSvc and choose Stop.
•Open the Task Manager, click the Processes tab, and then right-click AdappMgrSvr.exe and choose End Process.
•Type SERVICES.MSC into the Start menu to open the Services window, and then right-click Autodesk Desktop App Service and choose Stop.

Comment: @daidai all these process are already stopped, but in the "startup apps", I still see autodesk On and cannot turn it Off..